# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'?

Tags: python

```
def classify(file_path):
    global label_packed
    image = Image.open(file_path)
    image = image.resize((30,30))
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = np.array(image)
    pred = model.predict([image])[0]
    sign = classes[pred+1]
    print(sign)
```

Comment: I imagine classes is a dictionary?

Comment: Yes it is a dictionary

Comment: Probably you need to extract the number inside pred, add a print(pred) to see the shape of pred

Comment: What about this line sign = classes[pred+1]

Comment: Yes that the line of the error, because pred is a numpy array probably, you need to extract the value inside of it

Comment: Could you please rewrite the code for me. Mine's not working.